# Fetching multiple urls at a time gives me this Json result : {result: [ [Object]]}?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, fetch

I have a quick question thanks in advance for help.

I am fetching multiple urls from the bscscan testnet api.

I have 2 api and the first api is showing results in the browser but the second doesn't show anything, although the console shows me that the array is full of data and contained in an array.

For more information just ask me thanks !!

My Code in :

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'


export default function Home(props) {



  const datatransone  =  props.addresstransaction;
  const databalone = props.addressbalance;

  //something wrong with stringify
  // const datatransone = JSON.stringify(datatransjson);

  console.log(databalone);
  console.log(datatransone);

  return  (
    <ul>      
      <h1>Address One</h1>
      {databalone.map((balance) => {
        return (
      <li>{(balance.result * 1e-18).toString()}</li>
      )})}
      <div>
      <h1>Address Two</h1>
      {/* .result? */}
        {datatransone.map(transaction => (
            <div key={transaction.result}>
              <li >{transaction.timeStamp}</li>
              {/* <li>{transaction.hash}</li> */}
              <li >{transaction.from}</li>
              <li >{transaction.to}</li>
              <li >{(transaction.value * 1e-18).toString()}</li>
              {/* <li>{transaction.tokenName}</li>
              <li>{transaction.tokenSymbol}</li> */}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </ul>
  );
}


export async function getServerSideProps(context) {

    let wlunarush = ['0xb4e856c2a257457b862daed14967578bbdba3526', '0x52ab04656c807a3af96f98e4428291e813c2687a'];
    // let contractaddress = '0xde301D6a2569aEfcFe271B9d98f318BAee1D30a4';

    let balance = wlunarush.map(function(element){

      let bscbalance = 'https://api-testnet.bscscan.com/api?module=account&action=tokenbalance&contractaddress=0x0DBfd812Db3c979a80522A3e9296f9a4cc1f5045&address=' + element + '&tag=latest&apikey=E2JAJX6MAGAZUHSYIBZIEMKMNW9NZKPR7I';

    return bscbalance;
  })

    let transaction = wlunarush.map(function(element){

      let bsctransaction = 'https://api-testnet.bscscan.com/api?module=account&action=tokentx&contractaddress=0x0DBfd812Db3c979a80522A3e9296f9a4cc1f5045&address=' + element + '&page=1&startblock=0&offset=1&endblock=999999999&sort=asc&apikey=E2JAJX6MAGAZUHSYIBZIEMKMNW9NZKPR7I';

    return bsctransaction;
  })



    const addressbalance = await Promise.all(balance.map(u => fetch(u)))
    const addresstransaction = await Promise.all(transaction.map(e => fetch(e)))


  // console.log(bscbalancelist)
  // console.log(bscbalancelist);
  // const responsesec = await fetch(transaction);
  // const bscbalancelist = await bscbalone.json();


  return {
    props: {
      addressbalance:  await Promise.all(addressbalance.map(r => r.json())),
      addresstransaction:  await Promise.all(addresstransaction.map(p => p.json())),
    }
  };


}
```

Here we have the first api that works and the second that does not work when mapping the array :

```
[
  { status: '1', message: 'OK', result: '127685053508969645992646' },
  { status: '1', message: 'OK', result: '4397370954949256160000000' }
]
[
  { status: '1', message: 'OK', result: [ [Object] ] },
  { status: '1', message: 'OK', result: [ [Object] ] }
]
```

JSON.stringify() results :

```
[{"status":"1","message":"OK","result":[{"blockNumber":"11964161","timeStamp":"1630428755","hash":"0x7b7bb2339189aaa56df0d98a5cf49c1ab2a09ce77e65333c84020e9d4e59f1a0","nonce":"435","blockHash":"0x80ee10d067b111d7c39a37ef245b7096c846a633dbc6182b7f2a3d934541140a","from":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000","contractAddress":"0x0dbfd812db3c979a80522a3e9296f9a4cc1f5045","to":"0x52ab04656c807a3af96f98e4428291e813c2687a","value":"0","tokenName":"Kaiju Worlds","tokenSymbol":"Kaiju","tokenDecimal":"18","transactionIndex":"2","gas":"6721975","gasPrice":"20000000000","gasUsed":"1073046","cumulativeGasUsed":"1391203","input":"deprecated","confirmations":"6158963"},{"b...........
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Your `jsons` variable (which should be renamed) will be an array of the results of the fetches (so, an array of objects). `jsons` does not contain JSON, it contains an array of objects. You can use them at that point. So what is the actual problem?

Comment: Just to be sure you understand, JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: If the concern is the text `[Object]` in the `console.log` output, that's just the console showing a placeholder for the object instead of the object's actual contents. The contents are there, the console just isn't showing it. If you wanted to see the results as text, you could convert them back to JSON and output it: `console.log(JSON.stringify(jsons, null, 4));` But you don't need to do that unless you actually want to dump that data out to the console.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the fast answer! So the problem actually is that I have 2 api's and I am fetching data and displaying them using .map(). This is working for 1 of both api and the one that is not working doesn't show me the content of the Array in the console but just : [object]. I have never seen that before and thought it would be causing the problem, but thanks to your comment i know now that it is just a placeholder. So I will update my question and show you the .map() problem I actually have.

Comment: hey T.J. Crowder, I have updated the question.